# custom radio buttons trimmed

Tags: android, xml, radio-button, radio-group

iam making a custom radiogroup but it looks trimmed! .. i've tried to make the `scaleType="matrix"` but it gave the same result .. that's my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="554dp" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:button="@layout/radio"

 />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:button="@layout/radio"
 />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@layout/radio"
 />
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and that's how it looks like !
[image]

Comment: Could you post your whole Layout file?

Comment: @JoaoBiriba that's my whole file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that it takes the size of `android:text=""` so when i leave it like that it trims the custom button
so by adding 
`android:text="             "` the problem was solved